# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Could not initialize class org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext

Tags: spring, servlet-3.0, spring-test

We are using `Spring-test-4.0.6` jar in test scope in our project.  Under same project we also have `javaee-6.0` dependency in provided scope.

I am getting this error in test case

`Could not initialize class org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext at com.sample.TestWebDOMConfiguratorMultiple.setUp(TestWebDOMConfiguratorMultiple.java:77`)

Surprisingly replacing `Javaee-6.`0 dependency with `servlet-api-3.0.1` resolves this issue.

Note: `Spring-4.0.6` pom has compile time optional dependency on `servlet-api-3.0.1`.

Question is why is it working with `servlet-3.0.1` and not with `javaee 6.0` as we are trying 
to replace `servlet-api-3.0.1` with `javaee-6.0`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the exact Maven coordinates (i.e., `groupId`, `artifactId`, and `version`) that you are using to declare the Java EE 6 dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact artifact that you are referring to as `javaee-6.0` and without being able to see the full stack trace, it appears that your `javaee-6.0` dependency contains Servlet API 3.0; whereas, `spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE` explicitly requires Servlet API 3.0.1.

So that is likely the source of your problem.

Regards,

Sam